# In MQTT specification, why we can't set an "alias" for the topic when subscribing?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

MQTT v5.0:
https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901113

Just like in "PUBLISH", we can subscribe a single topic (.e.g. "a/b/c") with an alias "1". And the broker should keep the map of alias and topic for each client session. Thus the broker can publish messages with alias "1" to subscribers who have been subscribed topic "a/b/c". It will save a lot of resources in transmission. It's there any reason for why MQTT doesn't implement this feature?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [wording](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901113) used in the spec is important here:

> The sender decides whether to use a Topic Alias and chooses the value.

You will note that the word `sender` is used; not `client` or `broker`/`server`. The way this is worded means that the broker can decide to use a topic alias when publishing messages to clients. This has the potential to deliver the benefits you are looking for.

I'm not aware of any brokers that do this currently but it looks like the next version of Mosquitto will include a basic implementation ([docs](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/develop/man/mosquitto.conf.5.xml#L1204), [issue](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/1757)).

So I guess the answer to your question is that the spec does allow aliases to be used for messages sent from the broker to the client but not in the way you expected. As @romkey says this keeps things simple and it could be argued that the sender is best placed to know which topics should be assigned aliases.

Comment: Thanks! It's a great way to implement alias for subscribers